# How to apply where clause in Rails ActiveRecord when the value is not nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have `User` model and I want to apply some where clause only when the value is not `nil` and otherwise just discard the clause. Is there any better way than just use conditions like:

```
if ids.nil?
  User.where(active: true)
else 
  User.where(active: true, id: ids)
end
```

Is there more DRY way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally use something along these lines:

```
search = { active: true }
search[:id] = ids if ids

User.where(search)
```

Comment: Thanks @sergio. Way better.